# Какой UnmanagedType соответствует UnicodeString из Delphi?

Tags: c#, delphi, .net

Delphi (UnicodeString):

```
function ShowDelphiMsg(inputStr : UnicodeString) : UnicodeString; stdcall;
var a : UnicodeString;
begin
    ShowMessage(inputStr);
    a := 'Тест!';
    result := a;
end;
```

C#

```
[DllImport("Native.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
internal static extern string ShowDelphiMsg([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string inputStr);
```

Такой вариант отлично передает из C# в Delphi строку, Delphi выводит строку. Но основная проблема - ошибка при возврате строки из Delphi.

Впорос: Какой `UnmanagedType` соответствует `UnicodeString` из Delphi?

p.s. архитектура у обоих приложений `x64`.

---

Delphi (WideString):

```
function ShowDelphiMsg(inputStr : WideString) : WideString; stdcall;
var a : WideString;
begin
    ShowMessage(inputStr);
    a := 'Тест!';
    result := a;
end;
```

Так же вызывает ошибку при возврате значения.

---

Упростил функцию

C#:

```
 [DllImport("Native.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
 internal static extern string ShowDelphiMsg();
```

Delphi:

```
function ShowDelphiMsg() : WideString; stdcall;
var a : WideString;
begin
    a := 'Тест!';
    result := a;
end;
```

Та же ошибка.

Comment: А что, собственно, говорится в сообщении об ошибке?

Comment: AcessViolationException, тобишь ничего конкретного.

Comment: Не силен в C#, поэтому возможно скажу глупость, но: `string ShowDelphiMsg();` - не перекрывает ли оно предыдущее `UnmanagedType.BStr` ?

Comment: @kami, нет, тут все нормально.

Comment: Попробуйте в Delphi выполнить UnuqueString(Result) последней строкой.

Comment: @kami, не помогло.

Comment: @All, Ответ на вопрос (если есть желание - переводите, приму как ответ): http://stackoverflow.com/a/16170494/3061227

Comment: Т.е. всё решение - использовать `PWideChar`? Не верю, что с `WideString` оно не заработает. C# я совсем не знаю, поэтому утверждать не стану, что там это возможно. И если уж копировать строки через указатели, то можно и по-старинке `PAnsiChar` использовать и передавать однобайтовые строки или UTF-8 тот же. Удобство `WideString` как раз в том, что не нужно руками ничего никуда копировать, т.е. чтобы вот этого ужаса, что приведён в ответе, не видеть: `str = CoTaskMemAlloc(SizeOf(Char)*(Length('abc')+1));`

Comment: Нашел решение с `WideString` (обновил ответ). И не надо строки руками копировать.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по коду `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` тут используется `PWideChar`, что есть указатель на `WideString`. Из функции возвращать надо именно `WideString`.

**UPD:**

Оказывается, из-за особенностей C# (?) нужно использовать вот такой способ:

Delphi:

```
function SomeFunction2(out OutVar: Widestring): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  OutVar := 'Hello';
  Result := True;
end;
```

C#

```
[DllImport(@"Test.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SomeFunction2([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string res);
```

т.е. возвращать `WideString` через результат нельзя, а вот делать `out` параметр (но не `var` см. ответ Alex) - запросто.

Нагуглено: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331026/why-can-delphi-dlls-use-widestring-without-using-sharemem

Comment: Да, но на мой взгляд гораздо удобнее работать именно с `UnicodeString`, поэтому хотелось бы узнать какой тип соответствует именно `UnicodeString`.

Comment: C типом `UnicodeString` за пределами Delphi работать нельзя - это внутренний тип, с подсчётом ссылок.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Если не будет других ответов - приму ваш ответ.

Comment: Рекомендую справку по строковым типам: [String Types (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/String_Types_%28Delphi%29)

Comment: Хм, проверил, с `WideString` - та же ошибка. Сигнатуру Delphi добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @Alexis думаю, не будет. Delph-овские `string` и `UnicodeString` не имеют аналогов в других языках. Для передачи строк между модулями, имеющими (как минимум) разные менеджеры памяти нужно использовать общепринятые, известные всем типы. В Windows это WideString(BSTR), LPWstr(PWideChar). Приведите оба объявления к единому знаменателю Если LPWstr - то в Delphi должно быть PWideChar и на входе и на выходе. В C# в объявлении тоже, а сейчас в C# на выходе `string`

Comment: Так если вы возвращаете из Delphi строку, а не указатель, то это нужно указать: `UnmanagedType.BStr`

Comment: Упростил функцию, та же ошибка. Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: `var OutVar` - ошибка, должно быть `out`. С `var` это будет работать только случайно.

Comment: @Alex спасибо за уточнение, исправил ответ.

Comment: подскажите какой тип в делфи подходит для c# int (UnmanagedType.SysInt)?

Answer (score 3):

Проблема состоит в том, что Delphi и Visual Studio расходятся во мнении как трактовать соглашение вызова `stdcall`.

Любая функция, возвращающая сложный (в т.ч. автоуправляемый) тип:

```
function SomeFunction: WideString;
```

Трактуется Delphi как:

```
procedure SomeFunction(var AResult: WideString);
```

В то же время, Visual Studio трактует её либо как:

```
procedure SomeFunction(out AResult: WideString);
```

Либо как:

```
function SomeFunction: Pointer; // действительно возврат через EAX/RAX
```

(в зависимости от того, какой именно тип используется в `Result` - размера `Pointer` или больше)

В результате из-за этих отличий мы либо получаем Access Violation, либо утечку памяти.

Варианты правильных решений:

1. (Самый правильный) Использовать `safecall` вместо `stdcall`
2. (Допустимый - ответ zed) Явно описывать выходной параметр на Delphi
3. (Хак - ответ Alexis) Привести `Result` к простому типу и вручную управлять им

Если интересно, можно [почитать](http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2013/04/plugins-9.html).

Answer (score 1):

В процессе изучения нашел еще один вариант, более приемлемый на мой взгляд:

Delphi:

```
uses ActiveX;

function GetWideString(str: WideString): TBStr; stdcall;
begin
   result := SysAllocString(POleStr(str));
end;
```

C#

```
[DllImport("Native.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
internal static extern string GetWideString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string inputString);
```